# Disable draging of the view by pressing and holding a mouse button while moving the cursor

Tags: qt, qml, flickable

I want to disable the dragging of my List view using **pressing and holding a mouse button while moving the cursor**. I am trying to implement some other feature such as multiple selection using this command. I would only like the scrolling to be enabled. The **interactive** property of the **flickable** totally disables the movement of the view. Is there some workaround for this?

Comment: What about putting a `MouseArea` over the `Flickable` and handle all desired interactions back to the `Flickable` itself. The rest can be handled as you need. Should work.

Comment: `flickableDirection: ...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there are some ways to achieve what you need, but the following solution works.

The idea is to have a `MouseArea` and set the `interactive` property to `false` when the signals `onPressed` and `onClicked` are emitted. `interactive` should be set to `true` again in the `onReleased` handler.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        ListElement {
            name: "ttt"
            number: "111"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "rrr"
            number: "222"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "sss"
            number: "333"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "xxx"
            number: "444"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "yyy"
            number: "555"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "zzz"
            number: "666"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "aaa"
            number: "777"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "bbb"
            number: "888"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "ccc"
            number: "999"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "ddd"
            number: "011"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "eee"
            number: "022"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "fff"
            number: "033"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: myList
        width: 180; height: 100
        clip: true

        Component {
            id: contactsDelegate
            Rectangle {
                id: wrapper
                width: 180
                height: contactInfo.height
                color: "lightblue"

                Text {
                    id: contactInfo
                    text: name + ": " + number
                    color: "black"
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onPressed: {
                        myList.interactive = false
                        console.debug("onPressed")
                    }

                    onClicked:  {
                        myList.interactive = false
                        console.debug("onClicked")
                    }

                    onReleased: {
                        myList.interactive = true
                        console.debug("onReleased")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        model: listModel
        delegate: contactsDelegate
        focus: true
    }
}
```

Comment: This will also disable the mouse scroll when I have my mouse button clicked. I need to have the scrolling enabled when the mouse button is pressed... Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Replace `myList.interactive = false` by `myList.flickableDirection = Flickable.VerticalFlick`. I hope it meets your requirements.